# Erasing last element of vector containter

Tags: c++, vector, erase

I've got some problem with segmentation fault while I want to remove element from vector container which is the latest one pushed in.

```
vector<client> :: iterator it;

for(it=ktab->begin(); it!=ktab->end(); ){
    if(it->KEY_w==key_w) ktab->erase( it );
    ++it;
}
```

How to cope with this problem?

Comment: Use the erase-remove idiom. No need to worry about iterator invalidation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vector<client> :: iterator it;

for(it=ktab->begin(); it!=ktab->end(); ){
    if(it->KEY_w==key_w) it = ktab->erase( it );
    else  ++it;
}
```

Though in such situations it is better to use member function erase with standard algorithm std::remove_it

Comment: This solution is the best for me. I can't use remove_if because my code is much more complex.

Answer (score 6):

With `ktab->erase(it)` you, obviously, invalidate `it`. In the statement immediately after it you increment the already invalid `it`. You probably want to use something along the lines of

```
ktab->erase(std::remove_if(ktab->begin(), ktab->end(),
                           [=](client const& c){ return c.KEY_w == key_w; }),
            ktab->end());
```

Note that the solution using `std::remove_if()` moves each element at most once. The other solutions may have a quadratic number of moves.

Answer (score 1):

When you delete the element through its iterator, the iterator becomes invalid. That is the reason why [`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) returns the first iterator after the deleted element. You can fix your code like this:

```
for(it=ktab->begin(); it!=ktab->end(); ){
    if(it->KEY_w==key_w) {
        it = ktab->erase( it );
    } else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
for(it=ktab->begin(); it!=ktab->end(); ){
    if(it->KEY_w==key_w) 
    {
       it = ktab->erase( it );
    }
    else
    {
       ++it;
    }
}
```

Iterators are invalidated after you call erase, but `erase` also returns a valid iterator that references the item after the one you just erased. Storing this return value in your iterator ensures the iterator in your loop remains valid.